# Callback function passed down too many levels becomes "not a function"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback

I have a simple callback function that is passed down from a parent down multiple levels to a component which activates it onClick.

```
const routeToChapter = (courseId: string, chapterId: string) => {
 // do something
}

<Sidebar
  routeToChapter={routeToChapter}
/>
```

And then sidebar passes it down 3 more children to the point where it can actually be triggered in a component like this:

```
export const ChapterTreeItem = ({
  routeToChapter,
}: Props) => {
  const onRouteToChapter = () => {
    routeToChapter(courseId, chapter.id as string)
  }


  return (
    <EditorTreeItem
      onDoubleClick={onRouteToChapter}
    /> ......
```

The problem is that onRouteToChapter is triggered, yet "routeToChapter" throws an error saying that "routeToChapter is not a function".

I experimented with a test callback that I passed from the immediate parent from the bottom child, which worked. And I moved it up 2 more levels before it stopped working and I got the same error. I'm unsure as to why this happens.

**EDIT**

I console.log'd the function "routeToChapter" at each level and it printed as a function, including in the bottom component. However, if I print it in "onRouteToChapter" when the function is called, it always returns as undefined. Strange

Comment: This should work, you probably have a typo somewhere else. Can you try to make a code pen or similar that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're explicitly passing the prop from each intermediate child down?

Comment: Yeah. And I double checked for typos, there are none. Also I'm using Typepscript, so all everything is typed. At the bottom child, Typescript registers it as a function correctly too.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

I had this component existing in 2 separate places, but I was only testing it where the parent didn't have the "routeToChapter" function in the parent, which meant it was calling undefined.